# vector<bool> constant member functions

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

The Josuttis book *C++ Standard Library second edition* mentions on pg 282 for `vector< bool >` :

> Note that the internal proxy type **reference** is used only for nonconstant containers of type vector< bool>. The constant member functions for element access return values of type **const_reference**, which is a type definition for bool.

Can you help me understand the above statement? So as I understand for `vector<bool>`, since an access via `operator[]` cannot access a bit, it returns a proxy reference class. Why is it then or how is it that for constant member functions that it returns a type that is an alias to `bool` ( type definition for `bool`) ? Or am I understanding the wording incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the proxy is that you can do both read and write a value:

```
 std:vector<bool> v(1, false);
 v[0] = true;
 bool value = v[0];
```

To be able to write a value you need some sort of target to write to. Normally, you can just use a reference to the value. However, there is no such thing as a reference to bit. Thus, `std::vector<bool>` returns proxy which holds a reference (or a pointer) to the word where the bit is to be stored and some indication of which bit is affected when it is set, typically a mask of the word.

When only reading a bit, the value can be extracted upon read. There is no need to remember the location and the bit. As a result, a `std::vector<bool> const` can return `bool` values directly.

Comment: Thanks! To dig slightly more, since vector<bool> has every element stored internally as a bit, does the operator[] function under the hood for a const std::vector<bool> actually convert the bit to an equivalent bool ( whose size is implementation defined but maybe assume 1 byte) and return bool value as you say? (So in other words, the work is done to just assign a 1 to a true and 0 bit to false and return as bool and it is done inside the operator[] function). In the case of non-const vec element access, it returns a ref proxy and work is done outside the operator[] by the operator bool() ?

Comment: @avish: yes. For a `std::vector<bool> const` the extraction of the bit from the representation is done before a result is returned from `operator[]()`. In case of `std::vector<bool>` the result returned from `operator[]()` may be read or written to but what is being done is only determined after `operator[]()` returns. As a result the proxy needs to hold the additional information.